# Synchronization of Amazon MWS and Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, amazon-mws

I'd like to be able to update a Google Sheet and then post the update to an Amazon Seller account. Is it possible to post to an Amazon Seller account, or will I have to do the opposite? The purpose is to be able to sell things both online and brick and mortar, while maintaining a consistent inventory count.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a software, in this case, a windows service that consistently reads the spreadsheet maintainable by the users. Unfortunately, it is important that they will not modify the columns as it maps exactly to my actual data model. The software is utilizing Google Spreadsheet API to be able to read the spreadsheet document. Another facet of the software is that it needs to use Amazon MWS SDK for it to get the supposed listing revisions towards the customer account in Amazon. So you will need to have an Amazon Developer account to accomplish this. I've recently been using MWS Feed API to accomplish bulk updates and avoid throttling.